# Купюроприемник CashCode SM выдает ошибку Rejecting due to Length(6CH)

Tags: c#

Купюроприемник **CashCode SM** выдает ошибку

```
Rejecting due to Length(6CH)
```

Какова основная причина этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка Rejecting due to Length(6CH) указывает, что купюра длинная или короткая.

Возможно оптодатчики загрязнились - почистите их

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ

Comment: Но до сегодняшнего дня все работало нормально, а сегодня начала выдавать эту ошибку.

Comment: Возможно оптодатчики загрязнились - почистите их